# What is the bug in STM32 hardware I2C?

Tags: stm32, i2c

I am from China,I was told that STM32 hardware I2C has bug.So I always use software simulation I2C with two ordinary GPIO Pins.
I was wondering what is the bug exactly?Is it a rumor ,or is it true?I hope get opinion from abroad website,because you speak English ,you may get more infomation first hand.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Each device may have some silicon faults. Go to the product web page and look for **Errata** documentation.

For example, [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/errata_sheet/es096-stm32f101x8b-stm32f102x8b-and-stm32f103x8b-mediumdensity-device-limitations-stmicroelectronics.pdf) is the errata for STM32F103, available on its [product page](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f103c8.html#documentation). There, you can see that it mentions some silicon faults related to I2C hardware.

Comment: notice most of the problems have workarounds. In fact, you rarely actually meet some problem that causes you to change implementation much. There is no problem in using I2C on STM32 if you're aware of potential problems and their workarounds. There is usually no reason to bitbang I2C on STM32, unless you have some very specific reason for that

Answer (score 2):

> that STM32 hardware I2C has bug

STM is manufacturing many lines of uCs and basically, their I2C implementations are pretty good. The only family having some issues in typical use cases is F10x but this family is old and NRFND.

So you can use I2C hardware without hesitation unless you mix 10 and 7 bits address mode or do similar very unusual things.

I have never encountered problems using F3, F4, F7 & H7 families.

Comment: Thanks,I have read errasheet,which honestly is difficult for me.Because I have not met the problems listed in the doc,so I don`t understand what it is exatly talking about.

Comment: Since they are rare in common use, I am not doing hi-tech work,just read/write oled screen,eeprom,or some kind of sensor.I will try it.